# LINQ Query question

Tags: c#, linq

I have a list with the following info

date, name, and a few statistics

The names can repeat, but they don't necessarily.

so for instance I could have

5, today, "John"
4, today, "Kim"
3, today, "Peter"
2, yesterday, "Kim"
1, yesterday, "Tim"

I want a query that retrieves the latest records for each user. In my example that would be records 5, 4 and 1.

Do I necessarily have to match each record against the whole database in order to find out?
What would be the best performing query to achieve this?

Comment: did you mean oldest instead of latest? why do you want to get 2 and not 4 if latest means newest? in SQL what you ask looks like Group by username and having Id = min...

Comment: oops, switched the numbers on the list on my last edit, forgot to change that too.

Comment: do you have the issue only in LINQ or also in SQL, can you tell us which SQL query gives you your expected result?

Comment: That's what I was wondering actually, I can't figure out how to do it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe something like this could work?

```
var linq = people.GroupBy(a => a.Name).Select(a => a.OrderBy(a => a.Date).Last());
```

Longer version:

```
var linq = from person in people
           group person by person.Name into grouped
           select grouped.OrderBy(a => a.Date).Last();
```

Comment: I think that it should be ordered by date.

Comment: One more issue: it doesn't work with Entity Framework. The last line must be `grouped.OrderByDescending(a => a.Date).FirstOrDefault()`. But in this case it generates strange sql-query with `outer apply`: http://pastebin.com/q1TMbtty

Answer (score 0):

Here's what I think:

```
from u in context.Users
group u by u.UserID into grouped
select grouped.OrderByDescending(g => g.Date).First()
```